# Changing theformat from factor to date in R

Tags: r, date, format

I'm still a newbie and need some help with my dataset in R. 
I have a dataset containing daily observations for weekdays. In this dataset I want to add the dates for the missing weekends and change the format of the date to "2010-03-04". 
The dataset looks as follows:

```
             Date    Price
2392 Mar 04, 2010 1,132.60 
2393 Mar 03, 2010 1,142.70 
2394 Mar 02, 2010 1,136.90 
2395 Mar 01, 2010 1,117.80
2396 Feb 26, 2010 1,118.30
2397 Feb 25, 2010 1,107.80
2398 Feb 24, 2010 1,096.50
```

I use the following to change the format:

```
as.Date(gold_future$Date, format = '%b %d, %Y')
```

```
           Date    Price
2392       <NA> 1,132.60
2393       <NA> 1,142.70
2394       <NA> 1,136.90
2395       <NA> 1,117.80
2396 2010-02-26 1,118.30
2397 2010-02-25 1,107.80
2398 2010-02-24 1,096.50
```

What happens is that some dates are changed to the correct format but for others I get NA's. Furthermore after formatting the "Date" column I would like to add additional rows for the missing weekends. Any suggestions how I can solve the problem with the dates and include the missing rows? Btw the date column is of class factor.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
    mutate(Date = mdy(Date))
#       Date    Price
#1 2010-03-04 1,132.60
#2 2010-03-03 1,142.70
#3 2010-03-02 1,136.90
#4 2010-03-01 1,117.80
#5 2010-02-26 1,118.30
#6 2010-02-25 1,107.80
#7 2010-02-24 1,096.50
```

---

The `as.Date` is also working

```
as.Date(df1$Date, "%b %d, %Y")
#[1] "2010-03-04" "2010-03-03" "2010-03-02" "2010-03-01" "2010-02-26" "2010-02-25" "2010-02-24"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Date = c("Mar 04, 2010", "Mar 03, 2010", "Mar 02, 2010", 
"Mar 01, 2010", "Feb 26, 2010", "Feb 25, 2010", "Feb 24, 2010"
), Price = c("1,132.60", "1,142.70", "1,136.90", "1,117.80", 
"1,118.30", "1,107.80", "1,096.50")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("2392", 
"2393", "2394", "2395", "2396", "2397", "2398"))
```